# TypeError on pickle.load with class derived from SimpleNamespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, pickle

Consider this Python (version 3.5) code:

```py
import pickle
from types import SimpleNamespace

class MyClass1(list):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.append(x)

class MyClass2(SimpleNamespace):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

a0 = SimpleNamespace(x=99)
a1 = MyClass1(99)
a2 = MyClass2(99)

print('* SimpleNamespace:', pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(a0)))
print('* MyClass1:', pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(a1)))
print('* MyClass2:', pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(a2)))
```

This works fine for the first two (a0 and a1), but upon handling a2 I get an error:

```
* SimpleNamespace: namespace(x=99)
* MyClass1: [99]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./picktest.py", line 20, in <module>
    print('* MyClass2:', pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(a2)))
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

Observations:

- `SimpleNamespace` can be pickled.
- A class derived from a different type (`list`) can be (un)pickled.
- A class derived from `SimpleNamespace` cannot be unpickled if it has an `__init__` requiring arguments. (The error occurs in `pickle.loads`)

Note that I tried replacing `self.x = x` by just `pass` and that didn't change anything.

Is there a way to make this work other than by reimplementing MyClass2 without inheritance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `SimpleNamespace` defines a `__reduce__` that `pickle` uses to unpickle your object. The `__reduce__` defined in `SimpleNamespace` is not, however, consistent with your `__init__`. You can define your own `__reduce__` to skirt around this:

```
import pickle
from types import SimpleNamespace

class MyClass1(list):

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.append(x)

class MyClass2(SimpleNamespace):

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __reduce__(self):
        return (self.__class__, (self.x,))

a0 = SimpleNamespace(x=99)
a1 = MyClass1(99)
a2 = MyClass2(99)

print('* SimpleNamespace:', pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(a0))) 
print('* MyClass1:', pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(a1)))
print('* MyClass2:', pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(a2)))
```